# Правильное окончание

Tags: грамотная-речь, родительный-или-винительный

Вопрос, наверное аналогичный недавнему "винительный vs родительный падеж", но все-таки. Мне встретилось такое предложение: "Далеко не сразу он вспомнил, что очков больше не носит..." Разве "очков", а не "очки"? Или можно и так, и этак?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конструкциях, где при переходных глаголах с отрицательной частицей НЕ могут употребляться существительные в винительном и родительном падежах, в случае, когда существительное стоит во множественном числе, чаще всего используется родительный падеж. Поэтому: "Далеко не сразу он вспомнил, что **очков** больше не носит..."

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае я бы тоже предпочел скорее "не носит очки", а не "не носит очков".
Существительные, имеющие только множественное число, гораздо более тяготеют к сохраниению формы винительного падежа.
Хотя все равно, главное - контекст.

Как-то так:
Не носит очков - вообще (имеет хорошее зрение или пользуется линзами).
Не носит очки - конкретные (стесняется и держит в кармане).
Имхо, конечно.

Comment: Согласна с вашим замечанием. Но в приведенном контексте, как мне кажется, речь идет не о конкретных очках (например, в роговой опреве), а об очках вообще.

Comment: Ой, не знаю... По мне так "приведенный контекст" оставляет простор для воображения самой необычностью ситуации. Особенно мне, человеку, очки пока что не пользующему (тьфу-тьфу-тьфу). Так что не судите строго мою имху.

Но вообще-то я свои соображения привел для полноты картины, а не как конкретную рекомендацию.